# white container with cycle plugin in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I created a  slideshow of html pages using the cycle plugin. It works well with all browsers except for IE7. It displays a white page just the slide of image and not the caption.

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

try to add css-property to your block:

```
zoom:1;
```

otherwise, we need a code to inspect mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code for trailing coma's in objects, IE doesn't handle them well unlike other browsers